# IndexError: index 248 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 248

Tags: python

```
length = int(y.size/512) + 1  #length  5168
label_musicl = np.zeros(length)
lenth_beaat_frames = beats_frames.size # length 248
j = 0
for i in range(len(label_musicl)):
    if i == beats_frames[j]: 
        label_musicl[i] = 1
        j+=1
```

there is my code, when I try to run the code , the Indexerror always happend. really comfused, need some help..LOL

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sftf.py", line 39, in <module>
if i == beats_frames[j]: 
IndexError: index 248 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 248
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work :

```
for i in range(len(label_musicl)-1):
```

because when you use len() it gives you the absolute number of length and the index in python start with 0 not 1